# How to query google custom search engine for multiple keywords?

Tags: http, get, search-engine, google-custom-search

According to the https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?
key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=flowers&alt=json
```

If I replace flowers with skyblue I get a response with number of search results. But I want a response for "sky blue"

I tried using q=sky%22blue and sky+blue, I am getting errors. How to query with multiple keywords?

Comment: q=sky%20blue is the first thing to try

Comment: Its weird, but if %20 doesn't work, I think you might have to use this: `q=sky\ blue` http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/commerce-search/sxo5NQ5iAI0

Comment: @twiz sky/blue solves the issue. Create an answer so I can choose it. It will help others who are in a similar predicament.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space needs to be escaped with a backslash:

`q=sky\ blue`

Here is a similar question about escaping characters that may help:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/commerce-search/sxo5NQ5iAI0